# How to direct from one tab to another tab in a tab panel in php?

Tags: php

I have a html design with me which has tab panels with me. When i am clicking the continue button in the first tab in the panel. it goes automatically to the second tab. But after I have written the php code for the first tab(first tab contains a form) when i click the submit button of the form in the first tab, it goes to the second tab(stays only for a second on the screen) and then returns to the first tab.

**form(first tab form):**

```
<form name="customer" id="customer" method="post" action="step2">


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Continue</button>  


 </form>
```

Here step2 is the id of the second tab panel when i am writing the php code for the form in the first tab. But it doesnot go to the second tab. Can anyone say y it is like that ? I am writing the code for tab panel the first time.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the submit button on a form the form will be posted to the server, this is all handled by the browser without you having to write any code for it. You can use ajax to send the data from step1 and use preventDefault() to stop the browser from also sending the data, or you could have the php script getting the data to set step2 as active in the same way as you do it on the client side now

Comment: how to set step2 active using php script ?

Comment: in the code step2 is given inside the form tag in the action attribute.

Comment: The simple solution is to have step1 and step2 as individual pages, but you could also look into using ajax to help you. You could also look at the network traffic in your browser to better understand what is happening